# Prove that the minimum value of all products of two values is less than $-\frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction, maxima-minima, geometric-topology

> Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be $n$ real numbers, where $n \geq 3$ is an odd natural number. We know that:
> $$x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots + x_n^2 = 1$$
> and:
> $$x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \dots + x_n^3 = 0$$
> Prove that the minimum value of a product of type $x_ix_j$, with $0 < i < j < n +1$ is less than $\frac{-1}{n}$.

My thoughts: Let's consider two points $P$ and $Q$ in the $n$-dimensional topological space, one defined by $P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ and the other by $Q(x_1^2, x_2^2, \dots, x_n^2)$. Obviously, from the first hypothesis, $P$ is located on the boundary of the $n - 1$-hypersphere. While, from the second condition, the scalar product $\vec{OP} \cdot \vec{OQ} = 0$, therefore $OP \perp OQ$ (perpendicularity defined in the $n$-space). From here, I want to find a $n$-geometrical condition for the collection of products, make their sum, and impose som condition on the smallest term.

Comment: Something is wrong here ... if you take $x_n = 0$ and $x_j = (-1)^i/(n-1)^{1/2}$ you get $\sum x_i = 0$ hence $\sum x_jx_j = -1/2$ and clearly $-1/2 < -1/n$. That is we do not need the second condition.

Comment: @Salcio We are asked to prove that the condition is satisfied for *all reals* for which **both** conditions are true. There might exist other sets of numbers, satisfying only one of the conditions or none which may be able to fulfill the property we are asked to prove. Thus, an example of numbers respecting only one of the two conditions and also satisfies the  final property sais nothing about the corectness of the problem in cause.

Comment: no, this is not what is stated in the problem. It says "Prove that the minimum value of a product ..." . Mind "minimum" not "for all...".

Comment: @Salcio It is about proving that the minimum value of all the products considered **for any particular configuration** is less than $\frac{1}{n}$, not about comparing all possible products of two real numbers and computing their hypothetical minimum.

Comment: Maybe my text *in the title* is not clear enough, but please check the more accurate formulation I provided in the main bofy of the post.

Comment: well ... somebody has problems with elementary logic here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140738/discussion-between-mathstackexchange-and-salcio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $a = \underset{1\le i\le n}{\min}{x_i}$ and $b = \underset{1\le i\le n}{\max}{x_i}$, then

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^3-a^3)(x_i^3-b^3)\le0 &\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^6-\underbrace{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 \right)}_{=0}(a^3+b^3)+na^3b^3\le 0 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow a^3b^3\le -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^6  \tag{1} \\
\end{align}$$
Applying the [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) for $(p,q)= \left(3,\frac{3}{2} \right)$
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i^2\right)^{3} \right)^{1/3}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1^{3/2} \right)^{2/3} \ge \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 =1$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^6 \ge \frac{1}{n^2} \tag{2}$$

From $(1),(2)$, we deduce that:
$$a^3b^3\le -\frac{1}{n^3} \Longleftrightarrow   \color{red}{ab\le -\frac{1}{n}}$$

The equality occurs if and only if $n=2k$ and for example $x_1=...=x_k = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $x_{k+1}=...=x_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Hence, the minimum value of a product of type $x_ix_j$ is less than  $-\frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ is odd number.

Q.E.D

Comment: Nice! It seems the condition of $n$ being odd was redundant. Right?

Comment: @RezaRajaei yes, if $n$ is odd, then the equality cannot occur. In order words, for $n$ odd, we have $$\min \{x_ix_j\}  \color{red}{<} -\frac{1}{n}$$